# Migrating django.dispatch.dispatcher from Django 0.96 to 1.0.2

Tags: django, google-app-engine, migration, django-signals

How does one perform the following (Django 0.96) dispatcher hooks in Django 1.0?

```
import django.dispatch.dispatcher

def log_exception(*args, **kwds):
  logging.exception('Exception in request:')

# Log errors.
django.dispatch.dispatcher.connect(
  log_exception, django.core.signals.got_request_exception)

# Unregister the rollback event handler.
django.dispatch.dispatcher.disconnect(
  django.db._rollback_on_exception,
  django.core.signals.got_request_exception)
```

Incidentally, this code is from [Google's Article on Using Django on GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html). Unfortunately the dispatch code in Django was rewritten between 0.96 and 1.0, and Google's example does not work with Django 1.0.

Of course, the Django people provided a [helpful guide](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.0-porting-guide/#signals) on how to do exactly this migration, but I'm not keen enough to figure it out at the moment. :o)

Thanks for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic difference is that you no longer ask the dispatcher to connect you to some signal, you ask the signal directly. So it would look something like this:

```
from django.core.signals import got_request_exception
from django.db import _rollback_on_exception

def log_exception(*args, **kwds):
  logging.exception('Exception in request:')

# Log errors.
got_request_exception.connect(log_exception)

# Unregister the rollback event handler.
_rollback_on_exception.disconnect(got_request_exception)
```